# Slingshot is not launching (Font-Error)

Tags: python, games

After having installed `slingshot` (Version 0.9-1 from the universe repository) on 16.04 i tried to start it by executing `slingshot` in the terminal.

The output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/games/slingshot", line 61, in <module>
    class Game:
  File "/usr/games/slingshot", line 67, in Game
    Settings.font = pygame.font.Font(get_data_path("FreeSansBold.ttf"), 14)
IOError: unable to read font filename
```

The font itself is installed on my system, according to the output of `locate FreeSansBold.ttf`

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf
```

Reference Links regarding slingshot:

- [Project GitHub](https://github.com/ryanakca/slingshot)
- [Listing at PyGame](http://pygame.org/project-Slingshot-428-.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Launchpad-Bug regarding this issue - see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/slingshot/+bug/1400460) for more details.

A comment there is mentioning that this issue should be fixed in 0.9-1 which is not true at least for me.

I was able to troubleshoot the broken symlink problem by running:

```
cd /usr/share/games/slingshot/data
sudo ln -sf ../../../../lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/freesansbold.ttf FreeSansBold.ttf
```

Comment: Good catch. But It should work with any other FreeSansBold file I guess? Though I don't know what this game is about